# What *exactly* does 'Shared Privately' indicate in the context of an activity from the Google+ Domains API?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-domains

Consider the following G+ **Domains** API Response payload (snippet):

```
{
   ...
   ,
   "provider": {
    "title": "Google+"
   },
   "access": {
    "kind": "plus#acl",
    "description": "Shared privately"
   }
}
```

What **exactly** does shared privately mean?  As far as I can tell, it's any type of activity that has not been explicitly shared publicly.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [activities resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities#resource) covers most of this. `description` is just the user visible name of the acl state. The `access.items[]` fields are what actually dictate the visibility of the activity. I believe that "shared privately" is generally used when a specific list of people have access to the post.